# Значок Суффикса / Корня В браузере

Tags: webbrowser, браузер, latex

Есть что либо такое ? Типо Латекса но для русского языка, чтобы можно было вставлять символы и отображать в браузере типо Суффикса или Корня ?

Comment: Оффтоп: LaTeX читается латех.

Comment: Посмотрите на [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). Вот [пример применения](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268637/can-a-function-exist-such-that-int-0-infty-s-fracxdx-fracxdx)

Answer (score 1):

да, имеются некоторые символы, похожие на то, что вам, видимо, нужно:

зна⃩к зна͆к зна͡к зна᷍к

без интерпретации:

`зна&#8425;к зна&#838;к зна&#865;к зна&#7629;к`

вот так они выглядят у меня на экране:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

посмотрите, например, в категориях:

- [комбинируемые диакритические знаки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks/)
- [комбинируемые диакритические знаки для символов](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks-for-symbols/)
- [дополнительные комбинируемые диакритические знаки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/combining-diacritical-marks-supplement/)

Comment: Сильно зависит от шрифта. И корень слова может быть любой длины.